# How to remove a folder from VS2008 Source Control, keeping the local folder intact?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, version-control

I have a working folder that's synced to a team server. I was wondering if there is a way to remove some of the subfolders (i.e., stop syncing them, and make them invisible to others), without actually deleting them on the local drive?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most source control providers do not delete the folders when they are removed from source control.  There are exceptions but I don't believe this is the standard behavior.  If it is though you can do the following to work around the problem

1. From explorer rename the directory and add the .backup extension
2. Remove the folder from source code control.  Since it's renamed it can't be deleted because source control can't find it
3. Rename the folder back to the original name.

Answer (score 1):

I think "Exclude from project" (by right clicking the folder/file in solution explorer) is what might help you.

Comment: Assuming this would work (i.e., that source control would know to stop syncing it), it cannot be done to subfolders. The folder I'm talking about isn't associated with a VS2008 solution, it's used to store intermediate output from a statistical package.